# Flot line connecting starting point and end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I am generating a graph using the flot library (v 0.8) which appears to be drawing a line between the starting point and end point of the data series.  I cannot seem to figure out why this additional line is being drawn, which you can see here:

[image: graph]

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHuyd/2/) to test with that show the issue (it's missing the flot time plugin, so i commented out the options related to it).

Here is the code:

```
var options = {
        series : {
                lines: { show: true },
                color : "#00E5EE"
        },
        xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%d %b %h:%M %P",
                timezone: "browser",
                tickLength: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
                tickLength: 0
        },
        lines: {
                show: true
        },
        points: {
                show: false
        },
        grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                aboveData: true,
        },
};
$("#placeholder").empty();
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], options);
```

Here is the data series:

```
[
  [
    1372428000000,
    0.01745128631591797
  ],
  [
    1372428060000,
    0.03703117370605469
  ],
  [
    1372428120000,
    0.32158660888671875
  ],
  [
    1372428180000,
    0.06702804565429688
  ],
  [
    1372428240000,
    0.06312179565429688
  ],
  [
    1372428360000,
    0.030078887939453125
  ],
  [
    1372428420000,
    0.13084697723388672
  ],
  [
    1372428480000,
    0.011885643005371094
  ],
  [
    1372428540000,
    0.09821128845214844
  ],
  [
    1372428000000,
    0.01745128631591797
  ],
  [
    1372428060000,
    0.03703117370605469
  ],
  [
    1372428120000,
    0.32158660888671875
  ],
  [
    1372428180000,
    0.06702804565429688
  ],
  [
    1372428240000,
    0.06312179565429688
  ],
  [
    1372428360000,
    0.030078887939453125
  ],
  [
    1372428420000,
    0.13084697723388672
  ],
  [
    1372428480000,
    0.011885643005371094
  ],
  [
    1372428540000,
    0.09821128845214844
  ]
]
```

Also using a little CSS to rotate the xaxis labels:

```
.xAxis > .tickLabel
{
    margin-top:40px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your times repeat; the first point - 1372428000000 - repeats ten points later.

When Flot reaches that point in your series, it draws a line to the next point - back at the beginning - and then re-traces the rest of the plot.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot.  I was looking at everything but the data set for problems.  That fixed the issue, thanks for the help.